# Is Google Page Speed Service a competitor for CDN services

Tags: cdn

I've been googling around for a cheap CDN service and came across: http://code.google.com/speed/pss/index.html

This seems to be a competitor to other CDN services, is this the case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, judging from the [faq](http://code.google.com/speed/pss/faq.html#limitations) it proxies pages and images (up to 50M) and follows up visits (how many? all of them? wasting bandwidth?) and POST requests (up to 2M) to the original site.

It does **not** serve **videos** or **swfs**, and I suppose zip files too are out of question.

It proxies requests, but it modifies your webpages (to improve speed, yeah) this part of the service could break some scripts.

It sounds good, as long as it stays free, but it's hard they keep it so after testing is over.
For a small fee, the amazon competition still looks in good shape.

***The best thing*** about it, to me, is the fact the setup may happen ***during worst case/slashdot scenarios***, when you have no access to the overloaded server, but the DNS panel of your registrar may still be functional.

***The worst thing*** is that *it's not clear* if in such scenario your server would be actually freed of the pression and clear to operate or *just clogged back again* in by the google proxy. I suppose it woud be freed, but the ***details on that are quite important*** and not clear. *(as the service is **not officially focused on availability**)*

It may be a google way to shovel the *google apps* network of servers back in niches where it cannot go because of their choice of python as a programming language, *but that's just a hunch I have.*

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I have recently come across a few free ones. The best that I have seen are:

http://www.incapsula.com/
https://www.cloudflare.com/

They have some security and other benefits also. Worth checking out.

For some more information on what there is available out there it is also worth checking out http://cloudharmony.com. They do benchmarks and give out information on the major competitors.

But from what I understand, for large commercial websites it's still better to use a CDN. These kind of speed up services are still a but buggy. Some of the speed up services also integrate a spam protection which can be buggy sometimes and block people.

Note that the bug CDN's as amazon etc are not that expensive, only a few cents per gig.